# Javascript Navigator Object

Tags: javascript

If I write this:

navigator.plugins

I get this:

[object PluginArray]

If I write this:

navigator.plugins[0]

I get this:

[object Plugin]

**How can I get the real name of the plugin.**

Same is true for:

navigator.mimeTypes

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need:

```
navigator.plugins[0].name
```

Comment: Thanks worked for plugin but for navigator.mimeTypes[0].name I get "undefined"

Comment: Ah, the mimeTypes object has 3 string members that might help: description, suffixes, and type. For example: navigator.mimeTypes[0].type etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the console to explore the structure of the plugins array:

```
console.dir(navigator.plugins);
```

Comment: Where would I have to enter that code in the application console or like that in javascript? Thanks!!